# hql query to retrieve top n from each group

Tags: hibernate, hql

i want to achieve the following in HQL -

**select top n from table1 where table1.id IN (some select sub query)**

i have found the setMaxResult(n) method, but it can only retrieve top n of the entire result.. but what i want to achieve is top n of each group...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Here is JPQL you need:

```sql
select a from Employee a
where
(
    select count(*) from Employee b
    where 
       a.department = b.department and
       a.salary <= b.salary
) <= 10
order by salary DESC
```