# Unable to convert SQL which is meant for greatest N per group to HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables in Oracle namely `product` and `product_image`. As the names imply they have a one-to-many relationship from `product` to `product_image.`

The `product` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT", catalog = "", schema = "WAGAFASHIONDB")
public class Product  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PROD_ID", nullable = false, precision = 35, scale = 0)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "productIdSequence", sequenceName = "PRODUCT_SEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "productIdSequence")
    private Long prodId;
    @Column(name = "PROD_NAME", length = 50)
    private String prodName;
    @Column(name = "PROD_CODE", length = 50)
    private String prodCode;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "PROD_DESC")
    private String prodDesc;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "MARKET_PRICE", nullable = true, precision = 35, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal marketPrice;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "SALE_PRICE", nullable = true, precision = 35, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal salePrice;
    @Column(name = "PROD_FEATURED")
    private Short prodFeatured;
    @Column(name = "EXPRESS_DELIVERY")
    private Short expressDelivery;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PROD_WEIGHT", nullable = true, precision = 35, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal prodWeight;
    @Column(name = "PROD_OCCASSION", length = 50)
    private String prodOccassion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "QTY_AVAILABLE", nullable = true)
    private BigInteger qtyAvailable;
    @Column(name = "LATEST")
    private Short latest;
    @Column(name = "VISIBLE")
    private Short visible;
    @JoinTable(name = "PRODUCT_SIZE", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PROD_ID", referencedColumnName = "PROD_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "SIZE_ID", referencedColumnName = "SIZE_ID")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<SizeTable> sizeTableSet;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productSet", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Colour> colourSet;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prodId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Measurement> measurementSet;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prodId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Wish> wishSet;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prodId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Cart> cartSet;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prodId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ProductImage> productImageSet;             //<--------



    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<OrderItem> orderItemSet;
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUB_CAT_ID", referencedColumnName = "SUB_CAT_ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Subcategory subCatId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "FABRIC_ID", referencedColumnName = "FABRIC_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Fabric fabricId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "BRAND_ID", referencedColumnName = "BRAND_ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Brand brandId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prodId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Inquiry> inquirySet;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prodId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Rating> ratingSet;
}
```

The `ProductImage` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_IMAGE", catalog = "", schema = "WAGAFASHIONDB")
public class ProductImage  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PROD_IMAGE_ID", nullable = false, precision = 35, scale = 0)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "productIdSequence", sequenceName = "PRODUCT_IMAGE_SEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "productIdSequence")
    private Long prodImageId;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "PROD_IMAGE")
    private String prodImage;
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROD_ID", referencedColumnName = "PROD_ID")



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Product prodId;           //<--------------
}
```

I need to fetch only rows for the maximum `prodId` for each group of rows (actually each group of products) in `ProductImage` i.e the greatest N per group.

The Oracle native SQL can be constructed as follows.

```
SELECT pi.prod_image_id, pi.prod_id, pi.prod_image 
FROM product_image pi 
INNER JOIN (select max(pi.prod_image_id) AS prod_image_id, pi.prod_id FROM product_image pi GROUP BY pi.prod_id) prod_image 
ON pi.prod_image_id=prod_image.prod_image_id
```

This works exactly as intended but I couldn't convert this SQL to HQL. Trying to execute directly as HQL in the `createQuery()` method causes the `QuerySyntexException`, unexpected token at the very first opening parentheses. Could you please given me a hint to convert this SQL to HQL?

---

**EDIT:**

Some questions like the following haven't yet answered to accomplish this as it actually means:

- [Best way to use hibernate for complex queries like top n per
  group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/618951)
- [hql query to retrieve top n from each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4264528)
- [Using HQL with MySQL how can I order the result set before the group
  by so the right record is picked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7561868)

I think, there is no way to achieve this in Hibernate through HQL. I may need to break this SQL to appropriate two or more HQL statements using some DTO classes. If it is possible through a single HQL statement like the SQL above, then please don't forget answer here, since I have such requirements at **too** many places in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
select 
    pi.prodImageId, 
    pi.prodId 
from 
    ProductImage pi 
where 
    pi.prodImageId in (
    select max(pis.prodImageId)
    from Product p
        inner join p.productImageSet pis
    group by p.prodId
)
```

which translates to:

```
select
   productima0_.prodImageId as col_0_0_,
   productima0_.prodId_prodId as col_1_0_,
   product1_.prodId as prodId18_,
   product1_.name as name18_ 
from
   ProductImage productima0_ 
inner join
   Product product1_ on productima0_.prodId_prodId=product1_.prodId 
where
   productima0_.prodImageId in (
      select max(productima3_.prodImageId) 
      from 
         Product product2_ inner join ProductImage productima3_ on product2_.prodId=productima3_.prodId_prodId 
      group by product2_.prodId
   )
```

which is what you want i guess?

Comment: This indeed works right. Actually, I have trimmed the SQL to reduce the complexity. It could be worth for me only when the result set retrieved by this HQL can further be left joined with the `product` table like this SQL `SELECT p.*, t.prod_image, t.prod_image_id FROM product p LEFT JOIN(select pi.prod_image_id, pi.prod_id, pi.prod_image FROM product_image pi INNER JOIN (SELECT max(pi.prod_image_id) AS prod_image_id, pi.prod_id from product_image pi group by pi.prod_id) prod_image ON pi.prod_image_id=prod_image.prod_image_id)t ON p.prod_id=t.prod_id ORDER BY p.prod_id DESC;`.

Comment: This doesn't seem possible. Can this be made possible? Many thanks.

Comment: I think yes. Just add `Product` to the outer `select`, HQL supports left joins.